# Query Data From Firebase using recyclerview didn't show result

Tags: android, firebase

i Have a firebase database as shown in image

[Firebase database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZJh2.jpg)

Then i tried to search/query data based on username child using recyclerview

```
   text_to_search=textsearch.getText().toString();
                userprofilref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
                FirebaseRecyclerOptions<UserFileData> options =
                        new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<UserFileData>()
                        .setQuery(userprofilref.orderByChild("username").equalTo("Aldinsan"),UserFileData.class)
                        .build();

                FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UserFileData,UserViewHolder> adapter =
                        new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UserFileData, UserViewHolder>(options) {
                            @Override
                            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserViewHolder userViewHolder, int position, @NonNull UserFileData users) {

                                userViewHolder.txt_view_username.setText(users.getUsername());
                                userViewHolder.txt_view_userid.setText((users.getUserUid()).substring(2,7));
                                userViewHolder.btn_view_status.setText("Add");

                            }

                            @NonNull
                            @Override
                            public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_user_view, parent, false);
                                UserViewHolder userViewHolder = new UserViewHolder(view);
                                return userViewHolder;
                            }
                        } ;

                list_search_result.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.startListening();
```

Already created layout, viewholder and Userfiledata class.. but the query won't work.. this code previously work on my other project.. and i can't find out what is wrong or missing..

Comment: Please add the content of your `UserFileData` class.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
 .setQuery(userprofilref.orderByChild("username").equalTo("Aldinsan"),UserFileData.class)
                        .build();
```

change to

```
.setQuery(userprofilref.orderByChild("username").equalTo(text_to_search),UserFileData.class).build();
```

Comment: i knew, it's also not work  so i tried directly search username that equal to "Aldinsan" and still is not shown.

Comment: Do you have this line in your code?  'recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));'